# Pattern for large hash creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I'm filling a large (155-field) PDF using pdftk. I create massive hashes with the PDF's field names and the values to be filled in.

`PdfJob` collects all data from a model into a hash, and passes that hash into a [wrapper around `pdftk`](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) stored in `$PDFTK`.

```
class PdfJob
  def perform(model)
    $PDFTK.fill_form('path/to/fillable.pdf', Tempfile.new, Fields.call(model))
  end

  private

  class Fields
    def self.call(model)
      {
        OWNER_NAME: "#{model.first_name} #{model.last_name}",
        TOTAL_PRICE: calculate_total_price(model),
        FOO: 'bar',
        # 152 more lines of key/value pairs.
      }
    end

    def self.calculate_total_price(model)
      # Most of these methods are multi-line.
      model.item_relations.sum(&:price)
    end

    # about 50 more class methods to simplify assignment in #call()
  end
end
```

I'm looking for a design pattern or some other way to break this hash into multiple classes, methods, or some other units so I don't end up with a `Fields` class with nearly 250 lines of near-untestable key/value pairs and helper methods.

Comment: I think the first step to splitting up the `.call` method, would be to add the keys step-by-step to the hash, instead of using one huge literal. For example you would do `result = {}`, then `result[:foo] = "bar"` (and many more lines like it), and then at the end `return result`.

Comment: @maxpleaner  in the actual implementation is is that way because I have a few loops that add to the keys as they go.  The initial `fields` hash still has a large amount of direct associations in it, though.  I left out the step-by-step to KISS the example for Stackoverflow.  Would the question be improved switching to that in the example?

Comment: Why not write your tests first? TDD may help you find a better way.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I have tests for the `Fields` class to ensure the hash contains expected values.  However, given the current design, I will have *at least* 155 assertions for the one class, which seems like an equally bad code smell.

Comment: How is filling 155 key-value pairs with 155 calls a code smell? Who said 155 assertions is wrong (hint: they were never dealing with real-world problems)? Once you have 155 fields, you have 155 methods and 155 assertions (I would go with one assertion checking all 155 fields, but that’s me.)

Comment: @JackM hit me up. No private messages here and exegete.net is expired.